# R lm package multiple variable regression

Tags: r, linear-regression, lm, predict

I have a data frame with 15columns. All columns have numeric data. The column names are A, B,C,D,E,....

I need to realise equation of line that fits B,C,D,E...S,T in relation to A. So basically I want to determine theta0, theta1, theta2 etc that fits the following equation:

A= theta0+ B*theta1+ C*theta2 + ...+ theta18*T.

Using following code, I am able to find this by using lm package:

```
M1= lm(A~(B+C+D+E....+S+T),dataframeName)
```

Question:
Can I replace the B+C+D+...+S+T expression by some smarter 'short-cut' expression. With above implementation I have to write the names of all 18 column names that I have to fit. Especially, if column names are long, I have to tediously write all the 18 variables in the same line.

Any suggestions?

Comment: you can try `lm(A ~ ., data = dataframeName)`, where `.` represents all other variables.

Comment: Hi, Thank you for your reply. I am wondering with above representation, how would I be able to realize transformations such as using 'square' in relationship     A= theta0+ theta1*(B^2)+ theta2*(C^2) + ...+ theta18*(T^2) . Similarly, if I want to use some other transformation such as log etc.